# Extract only the number from a ref in erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I'm new to Erlang.
I need to take only the number returned from make_ref().
so, if make_ref() returns :#Ref<0.0.0.441>
I would like to extract from it the 441.

any idea how to do this?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I need to create a uniqe number and the ref has it in it

Comment: There is no guarantee that the ref has a unique number in it. The ref is guaranteed to be unique, but the numbers are the _representation_ of the ref as a string. This is definitely not be right way of generating unique numbers.

Comment: Also note that modern Erlang runtimes have the `erlang:unique_integer` function, which does exactly that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
unique_integer() ->
    try
        erlang:unique_integer()
    catch
        error:undef ->
            {MS, S, US} = erlang:now(),
            (MS*1000000+S)*1000000+US
    end.
```

**Edit**:
The main difference between this solution and extracting integer using `io_lib:format("~p", [Ref])` is speed. When my solution takes around 40ns in R18, transformation to a list, regexp and back to an integer takes 9µs. I would go for two orders of magnitude faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `erlang:ref_to_list/1` function to convert a ref to a list, but the documentation warns against using it in production code. We can use `io_lib:format/2` instead. After converting the ref to a list, we can extract the numbers using a regexp.

Here's a function for extracting numbers from the string representation of a ref:

```
extract_from_ref(Ref) when is_reference(Ref) ->
    [RefString] = io_lib:format("~p", [Ref]),
    {match, L} = re:run(RefString,
                        "#Ref<(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)>",
                        [{capture, all_but_first, list}]),
    IntList = lists:map(fun list_to_integer/1, L),
    list_to_tuple(IntList).
```

To get only the last number of the string representation of a ref, you can use it like this:

```
{_, _, _, N} = extract_ref(make_ref()).
```